# Can't Repeat Column Groups AND ALSO hide Static Columns within a Matrix

Tags: ssrs-2008

**UPDATE**
When I first asked this question, I didn't fully understand what the problem was.  Your best bet is to glance over the issue below and then read my answer.

---

I have a report with a matrix where the data looks like the following:

```
Name    Id   Activity 1     Activity 2     …Acitivity N
Smith   1    77             100             nn
Johnson 2    88             99              nn
```

**Name** and **Id** are in a group.

When the number of activities are greater than 11, I need the columns **Name** and **Id** to repeat when the report renders in a PDF.

---

Here is an example of report recently run:

> Page 1 (NOTE:  red boxes indicate
>   personal data filtered out):

[image: Page 1]

---

Page 2:
[image: Page 2]

I've been fiddling with the properties *RepeatRowHeaders* and *RepeartColumnHeaders*, but I have had no success.

How do I make this column repeat?

Sadists can check out the rdl file [here](http://home.windstream.net/ray023/ssrs/MyReport.rdl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer (*and a plea from me*)**:

Please vote [on this Page](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=425175) to conditionally hide non-group matrix columns.

---

**Long Form:**

I found the solution to my problem, but first was figuring out the exact issue.  An SSRS Matrix has the ability to repeat columns on subsequent pages as its width grows when *RepeatRowHeaders* and *RepeatColumnHeaders* are set to True.  So that part of my report setup was fine.

My problem was that my grid was set up as follows:
[image: Grid 0]

What you see above is a Tablix containing a Matrix.  The blue represents a normal Tablix with four columns.  The green Represents a Matrix within Column 4 that has *N* number of columns.

So even with the properties *RepeatRowHeaders* and *RepeatColumnHeaders* set to true, Columns 1-3 would not repeat as the data in the Matrix extended to multiple pages.  This is because the outer Tablix (e.g. the blue part) only saw Column 4  as growing outwards instead of the individual columns in the inner matrix.

In order to make the columns repeat, I had to alter the grid like so:
[image: Static Columns]

This grid is only one matrix; not a Matrix within a Tablix as the first image depicted.  I pulled the matrix out and added "Static Columns" to the left.  This made Columns 1 - 3 repeat on multiple pages as the Matrix grew.

All seemed well, but here's the rub:  Static Columns cannot be hidden or, more aptly put, you can hide the data within a column, but the column itself will not shrink.

So, when I hid Static Column 3, my report looked something like this:
[image: Hiding Static Column]

Notice the white-space Gap.  This solution simply would not work.  When I found that I was stuck in an either/or situation (either have the ability to conditionally hide columns or Repeat Columns on Subsequent Pages), I used one of our Microsoft Support Incidents to analyze the report and come up with a solution.

Microsoft was nice and knowledgeable and even [pointed to a article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/5973417f-9d37-41c4-8c56-eeeb83d7f3c7) in their forum stating they were considering allowing SSRS to have the ability to hide static columns.  However, in the end, they said we were stuck with the either/or situation.  (BTW, note that forum thread was answered in 2006.)

So after that long process with Microsoft, we were still stuck with our dilemma.  Fortunately, one of our fellow programmers came up with a workaround:  put the columns you want to toggle visibility  within the Matrix itself.

And that's what I did.  It took some finagling with the report SQL (and creating a statement I'm not particularly proud of), but it works.

So now the working report looks like this:
[image: final matrix]

That's one Matrix, two static columns that *always* need to repeat on every page and Column 3 which is now part of the dataset used for the Matrix.

Once again, I plead with the community to vote [on this Page](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=425175) to conditionally hide non-group matrix columns.  It would make constructing future reports like this much easier :)